# Spark DataFrameWriter omits trailing tab delimiters when saving (Spark 1.6)

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, delimiter

*I am leaving my question below as it was originally posted for the sake of future developers who run into this problem. The issue was resolved once I moved to Spark2.0 - I.e. the output was as I expected without making any chnages to my original code. Looks like some implementation difference in the 1.6 version I used at first.*

I have Spark 1.6 Scala code that reads a TSV (CSV with tab delimiter) and writes it to TSV output (without changing the input - just filtering the input).
The input data has sometimes null values in the last columns of rows.

When I use the delimiter "," the output has trailing commas. 
E.g.

```
val1, val2, val3,val4,val5

val1, val2, val3,,
```

but if I use tab (\t) as a delimiter the output does not include the trailing tabs. E.g (I am writing here TAB where \t appears):

```
val1 TAB val2 TAB val3 TAB val4 TAB val5

val1 TAB val2 TAB val3  <= **here I expected two more tabs (as with the comma delimiter)**
```

I also tried other delimiters and saw that when the delimiter is a white space character (e.g. the ' ' characted) the trailing delimeters are not in the output.
If I use other visible delimiter (e.g. the letter 'z') it works fine as with the comma separator and I have trailing delimiters.

I thought this might have to do with the options ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace and ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace but setting them both to false when writing didn't help either.

My code looks like this:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "\t").load(params.inputPathS3)
df_filtered = df.filter(...)
df_filtered.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "\t").save(outputPath)
```

I also tried (as I wrote above):

```
df_filtered.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "\t").option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "false").option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "false").save(outputPath)
```

Comment: won't it write with the quotes like this `val1 TAB val2 TAB val3 "" ""`?

Comment: The output of this job is input to other jobs that don't expect to have quoted data. I need it to work and generate trailing tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working example(with spark 1.6):
Input file (with some trailing spaces in the end):

```
1,2,3,,
```

```
scala> val df = sqlContext.read.option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "false").option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "false").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", ",").load("path")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [C0: string, C1: string, C2: string, C3: string, C4: string]

scala> df.show
+---+---+---+---+---+
| C0| C1| C2| C3| C4|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+


scala> df.write.option("nullValue", "null").option("quoteMode", "ALL").mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "\t").save("path")

scala> sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "\t").load("path").show
+---+---+---+---+---+
| C0| C1| C2| C3| C4|
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Please refer: [this](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-csv.html) for all options while reading, writing with databricks csv library.

Comment: It works for me with comma as separator - it doesn't with tab as separator - that is the issue I'm trying to resolve.

Comment: I tried reading and writing with these options set to false but still got the same behavior I described. Which Spark version are you testing it on?

Comment: note also that your example input has data in it for the last columns (spaces) - my example has null values in these columns.

Comment: @Gaddy I have updated my answer according to your inputs. Please try it.

Comment: thanks for the update. Almost there... but I need the values to be without quotes, as the downstream processes assume no quotes. So I need the lines to end with a sequence of tabs without quotation marks for the null values (same as the tabs that appear for null values before the last sequence of null values. I tried quoteMode 'None' but then the trailing tabs were not in the output again.

Comment: you can achieve this if you provide a header in your CSV files. and use df.write.option("header","true").option("escape", "\\").option("quoteMode", "NONE").option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "false").option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "false")...

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I finally managed to get my output as I expected it to be, without making any change to my original code - just by moving to Spark2 (Spark2.3.0 by Cloudera to be more specific). I will update my question for the sake of future developers.